# Is there an API to script the ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We create Power BI Capacity but need to enable ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch using PowerShell/bash.

Is there an API we can call (given we are logged in as the correct admin) to avoid using the site

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-3---enable-the-power-bi-service-admin-settings

Comment: I believe there is no such API. This must be enabled and configured in Tenant settings.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> I agree with *@Andrey Nikolov*, it is not possible to enable
> `ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch` via any API.

**Note** that: The PowerShell **MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Admin** module doesn't include any commands to enable
`ServicePrincipalIsNotAllowedByTenantAdminSwitch`.

You can only enable it via [**PowerBI Admin Portal**](https://app.powerbi.com/admin-portal/tenantSettings) like below:

[image]

You can add service principal as a workspace member by using PowerShell like below:

```
Login-PowerBI

$SPObjectID = "ObjID"
$pbiWorkspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Filter "name eq 'WorkspaceName'"
Add-PowerBIWorkspaceUser -Id $($pbiWorkspace.Id) -AccessRight Member -PrincipalType App -Identifier $($SPObjectID)
```

[image]

**References:**

[MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Admin Module | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.admin/?view=powerbi-ps)

[Power BI content in an embedded analytics application with service principal | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#add-a-service-principal-or-security-group-by-using-powershell)